# Django Template / on which template I am and using IF for this template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-templates

Have a website that I have 1 div black rectangle used a as footer, data are pulled from DB inside the footer.

I would like to show this footer on every template that I have created in the django template directory except INDEX.HTML main page (template). If I put it into the BASE.HTML it will be everywhere, if I spread it to all my 20 templates except INDEX.HTML I would need to edit every each template for data in the footer I dont want to do that. How can I achieve footer is showing in all templates except INDEX.HTML but using it only once for editing data in the footer. Is there a django command or something like IF template = index.html hide the footer etc similar logic or what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`block` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#block) for this purpose.

> If you find yourself duplicating content in a number of templates, it probably means you should move that content to a `{% block %}` in a parent template

More [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

in `base.html`

```
{% block footer_content %}
    {# contents here #}
{% endblock %}
```

and in `index.html`

```
{% block footer_content %}
    {# this overwrites the base footer_content to empty block #}
{% endblock %}
```

This would remove the contents only in `index.html` and available on all other pages that inherit from `base.html`

Now, if you wish to add more content to certain pages,

```
{% block footer_content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {# more content here #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Woow, I didnt know it works also backwards thank you very much :)